# Output sum of decimal/float array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following which i thought would get me the sum of the array but doesnt:

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
   <% if Product.exists?(sku: order.line_items.where().map {|li| li.sku }) %>
      <%= order.line_items.where(vendor_name: @vendor.vendor_name).map do |li| %>
          <% if Product.exists?(sku: li.sku) %>
              <% product = Product.find_by(sku: li.sku ) %>
              <% ((li.store_price.to_d * li.store_fulfillable_quantity) - (product.production_price * li.store_fulfillable_quantity)) * (0.70) %>
          <% end %>
       <% end.compact.sum %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The output is something like:

`25.21 25.21 12.66 5.33 12.66 9.01`

I need to add these numbers.  How can I do this with the decimals/floats?

When I use

```
<%= @orders.each do |order| %>
```

I get `undefined method + for nilclass` for the line that is on, and it's not nil but obviously I'm missing some factor on how sum works.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Move the code out of the view code, provide minimal input data in `orders`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @orders.map do |order| %>
   <% if Product.exists?(sku: order.line_items.where().map {|li| li.sku }) %>
      <% order.line_items.where(vendor_name: @vendor.vendor_name).map do |li| %>
          <% if Product.exists?(sku: li.sku) %>
              <% product = Product.find_by(sku: li.sku ) %>
              <% ((li.store_price.to_d * li.store_fulfillable_quantity) - (product.production_price * li.store_fulfillable_quantity)) * (0.70) %>
          <% end %>
       <% end.compact.sum %>
   <% end %>
<% end.compact.sum %>
```

Is how i got it to work

Comment: Yes, I was just about to comment, it looks like you are summing the inner `map` but not the outer one. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

method `reduce` in arrays designed for getting reduced value of collection:

```
array.compact.reduce(:+)
# => Sum of array
```

more info about [reduce](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce)